# Change List Output after For Loop

Tags: apex, soql

I would like to exclude rows where Delta__c == Null. This can be done in 2 ways

1) only display odd rows using for loop
2) exlude rows where Delta__c == null

I am not sure how to modify list x after the For Loop. Can the same list be modified twice in APEX?

```
public with Sharing class EngagementDeltaController {



 public static Engagement__c[] getDelta() {

Engagement__c[] x = [SELECT Name, ID,Engagement_Score__c,CreatedDate,Account_ID__c,Delta__c FROM Engagement__c ORDER BY Account_ID__c,CreatedDate ASC];
if(!x.isEmpty()){
for(Integer i=1; i<x.size();i++)
{
    if(x[i].Account_ID__c == x[i-1].Account_ID__c)
    {
         x[i].Delta__c = x[i-1].Engagement_Score__c-x[i].Engagement_Score__c;        
      i++;
    }
    else system.debug('nothing found');
    }
   }
    return x;

 }
 }
```

Comment: You can modify a list e.g. use the remove method (or the add method) - take a look at the [list documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm). But the code might be better written filtering before or during your existing loop.

Comment: Perfect! x.remove(i-1); Worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a secondary list that stores the filtered results and return that instead of the original modified list.

```
public with Sharing class EngagementDeltaController {
  public static List<Engagement__c> getDelta() {
    List<Engagement__c> x = [SELECT Name, ID, Engagement_Score__c, CreatedDate, Account_ID__c, Delta__c FROM Engagement__c ORDER BY Account_ID__c, CreatedDate ASC];
    List<Engagement__c> filtered = new List<Engagement__c>();
    if(!x.isEmpty()){
      for(Integer i=1; i<x.size();i++) {
        if(x[i].Account_ID__c == x[i-1].Account_ID__c) {
          x[i].Delta__c = x[i-1].Engagement_Score__c-x[i].Engagement_Score__c; 
          if(x[i].Delta__c != null){
            filtered.add(x);
          }       
          i++;
        }
        else system.debug('nothing found');
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  }
}
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. Follow up question out of curosity: would it be possible to further filter the 'filtered' list e.g. display only the Top 10 records with highest Delta__c values?